# Send a variable as array from a checkbox form to another page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, custom-wordpress-pages

I need some help in the code below. I want to parse information from a custom_field (tech_spec_table) that contains a table with html tags of a blog/product (eg technical specs) only after the user has checked specific product/products and submitted (with a button) through a form in a blog-post. I have created a page "comparison-page.php" as a template page and try to link the action of the form on this page. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv1We.jpg)

```
// check if we got posts to display:
if (have_posts()) :

echo "<form method='post' action='<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/comparison-page.php' >";
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

      //the post

   echo "<article class='"....  >";
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='comparison[]' />";

     //the post

$post_loop_count++;
    endwhile;

        echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>";
        echo "</form>";
```

The comparison-page.php file is located into a custom theme under :wp-content/themes/custom-theme.
Here is the code for the comparison-page.php

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: comparison-page */ 
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php

           if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    //to run PHP script on submit

   if(!empty($_POST['comparison'])){
     // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
     foreach($_POST['comparison'] as $data_specs){

      echo $data_specs."</br>";

    $data_specs = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tech_specs_table', true);
    $dom = new domDocument;

    @$dom->loadHTML($data_specs);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

    $rows = $tables->item()->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        echo $cols[];
        }

    }
}
}       
        ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->



</div><!-- .content-area -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Although when i click the button leads to a 404 not found
1)What should i do to make the path invisible and connect correctly to the page?
2)Will the variable "comparison" save all the information from the form so i can get the post_meta information and manipulate in the comparison page?

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that WordPress doesn't work that way. You can't submit data to theme files like that.

What you need to do is have the page that you're submitting to use a custom page template and have your code for processing the form on that new custom page template.

So you're looking at having two custom pages with custom templates:
1) the form
2) the submission processor

The action for the form should take you to the submission processor.

Comment: Thanks, so you are saying that files in Appearance->Editor are template files?  
Can i include the generic handler to deal with all forms - admin-post.php. ?

Comment: Where possible, you shouldn't be using the editor at all (massive security risk, no backups), but yes, they are the theme files. You can set WP up to do just about anything if you understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be on line 3, when you define the form tag. You cannot open php tags inside a string! Instead, you can concatenate the string with the result of the `bloginfo` function with the `.` operator.

Comment: This is also your problem.

Comment: If i have understood when i tried the following :                                                                  
action=' ".bloginfo('template_url'); ."/comparison-page.php' >"; and this page won't load,

Comment: You have a semicolon in the middle of the line. Please enable display errors on your development environment, look up what they mean and try to fix them before posting. You would save a lot of time and effort by studying at least some basic concepts of the PHP language.

Comment: Rad80 you don't have to be rude.

Comment: Going to agree with @Rad80 here. You shouldn't do live changes like this, should be using a dev environment, and should be checking errors against the available sources *before* coming to StackExchange. SE is for helping with problems you can't figure out, not for basic how-tos.

Comment: First of all no one has to be rude. Second by your words the policy you refer should apply to all users that have committed basic how tos and StackExchange should be only for "advanced" problems. Besides someone doesn't have to answer if they don't like a basic question. Or you can just flag my "noob" case as long as many other's here also. But I'll keep in mind to use a debugger tool often.